# PHP Laravel BaseRepository CURL Error [ curl_setopt_array(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource ]

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

I have made a small and simple web app in Laravel for which I am using an API to fetch data from and visualize in a user-friendly way. To process/Fetch the data from API I have made a BaseRepository in my App, But I am getting this error: `"curl_setopt_array(): supplied resource is not a valid cURL handle resource"`

Here is how it looks like

[image: Here is how it looks like]

It would be great if anyone can help.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;


// Class BaseRepository.

class BaseRepository
{

    public $curl = null;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->curl = curl_init();
    }

    public function getAccessToken()
    {

        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://identity.vwgroup.io/oidc/v1/token",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MY_ID_GOES_HERE&client_secret=MY_CLIENT_SECRET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "Postman-Token: 84e72567-25d5-42ba-8a94-fe88e6bcc41d",
                "cache-control: no-cache",
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
        $err = curl_error($this->curl);

        curl_close($this->curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            // Convert JSON string to Object
            $responseObject = json_decode($response);
            $accessToken = $responseObject->access_token; // Access Object data


            return $accessToken;
        }
    }

    public function getCountries()
    {

        curl_setopt_array($this->curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.productdata.vwgroup.com/v2/countries",
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                "Accept: application/json",
                "Authorization: bearer " . $this->getAccessToken(),
                "Postman-Token: e6625e0a-fc50-4382-8812-8d151457dcab,67edecb8-64bd-4c93-9892-ec1061d5f210",
                "cache-control: no-cache,no-cache",
            ),
        ));

        $response = curl_exec($this->curl);
        $err = curl_error($this->curl);

        curl_close($this->curl);

        if ($err) {
            echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
        } else {
            // Convert JSON string to Object
            $responseObject = json_decode($response, true);
            $data = array('data' => $responseObject['data']);
            return $data;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: How are you calling these methods? Having `curl_close($this->curl)` at the end of each method is going to make it impossible to use in another method on the same class instance.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. You call `getAccessToken()` from `getCountries()`. See the problem with using `curl_close()` on the shared handle?

Comment: These methods are then called from my controller which then pass the information to my view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is one of your child repository classes is defining a `__construct()` method, and you are forgetting to call `parent::__construct()` inside of it, so the `curl_init()` method is never called.

Edit: The comment by Phil is another very possible cause to your problem. Calling `curl_close()` in one method will prevent the next from working with the shared cURL init.

I'd really suggest just moving `curl_init()` to each repository method. Your requests are not related, and might share different options and configuration. By modifying a single cURL instance, you might share options you didn't intend. It also lets you use `__construct()` in each of your child repository classes without worrying about BaseRepository and its constructor (which you can remove).

Comment: Thank you it worked just had to put it in the function `curl_init()`